# Open workbooks and move & copy a worksheet into a new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a code to open mentioned workbooks one by one and move & copy a particular worksheet into a new workbook

my code for the above mentioned task runs well till it opens the first file, then it gives me the following error
method or data member not found

```
Sub OpenFilesMoveCopyWorksheet()
    Const PTH As String = "C:\Users\xxx\yyy\" 'use const for fixed values
    
    Dim SFile As Workbook, SFname As Worksheet, SFname2 As Worksheet
    Dim SFlname As String, I As Long, DFile As Workbook
    Dim Acellrng As Range, ws As Worksheet, rngDest As Range, rngCopy As Range
    
    Set SFile = ThisWorkbook
    Set SFname = SFile.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    For I = 1 To SFname.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        SFlname = SFname.Range("A" & I).Value
        If Len(SFlname) > 0 Then

            Set DFile = Workbooks.Open(PTH & SFlname)
              
            If DFile.Worksheets.Name Like "*.cours" Then
            
            DFile.Worksheet.copyafter: SFile.SFname
                                
            End If
            DFile.Close savechanges:=False
        End If
    Next I
    
    MsgBox "job done"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

### Modified the code still getting "Run-time error'-2147221080 (800401a8)': Automation error"

Sub OpenFilesMoveCopyPaste()

```
Const PTH As String = "C:\xxx\yy\" 'use const for fixed values

Dim SFile As Workbook, SFname As Worksheet, SFname2 As Worksheet
Dim SFlname As String, I As Long, DFile As Workbook, I1 As Long, SFlname2 As String
Dim Acellrng As Range, ws As Worksheet, rngDest As Range, rngCopy As Range

Set SFile = ThisWorkbook
Set SFname = SFile.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For I = 1 To SFname.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    SFlname = SFname.Range("A" & I).Value
    
    If Len(SFlname) > 0 Then

        Set DFile = Workbooks.Open(PTH & SFlname)
          
   For I1 = 1 To SFname.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
   
   SFlname2 = SFname.Range("B" & I1).Value
   
  
   
   If Len(SFlname2) > 0 Then
   
        Set ws = DFile.Worksheets(SFlname2)
        
        ws.copy Before:=SFile.Sheets("sheet1")
               
        
        DFile.Close savechanges:=False
```

End If

Next I1

```
End If

 Next I

MsgBox "job done"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

### End Sub

### Final Version

Sub OpenFilesMoveCopyPasteSpecial()

```
Const PTH As String = "C:\XXX\YY\" 'use const for fixed values

Dim SFile As Workbook, SFname As Worksheet, SFname2 As Worksheet
Dim SFlname As String, I As Long, DFile As Workbook, I1 As Long, SFlname2 As String
Dim Acellrng As Range, ws As Worksheet, rngDest As Range, rngCopy As Range

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set SFile = ThisWorkbook
Set SFname = SFile.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For I = 1 To SFname.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    SFlname = SFname.Range("A" & I).Value
    
    If Len(SFlname) > 0 Then

        Set DFile = Workbooks.Open(PTH & SFlname)
        
        Debug.Print DFile.Name
          
    
   SFlname2 = SFname.Range("B" & I).Value
   
         Set ws = DFile.Worksheets(SFlname2)
        
        ws.copy After:=SFile.Sheets("sheet1")
        
        
        
        Cells.Select
Range("AO1").Activate
Selection.copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
              
        DFile.Close savechanges:=False
  




End If



 Next I

MsgBox "job done"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

 Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

End Sub

Comment: `DFile.Worksheets.Name` - the `Worksheets` collection has no `.Name` property.

Comment: `Worksheet.copyafter`. A `Worksheet` has no `.copyafter` method.

Comment: For this `If DFile.Worksheets.Name Like "*.cours" Then` you would need a loop that goes through all elements of `Worksheets`. Eg `For Each ws In DFile.Worksheets` and then you can check `If ws.Name Like "*.cours" Then` inside the loop.

Comment: The modified code only perform the activity once then gives " Run-time error'-2147221080 (800401a8)': Automation error" on the "Set ws = DFile.Worksheets(SFlname2)" part of the code

Comment: finally got it working after some changes